# Call a WebElement using parametrisation on PageFactory

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there anyway, I can call my web elements with Parameterisation, so that I use them on my any of the methods.

Like Let's suppose I want to interact with table records, for that I am using :

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//tr[@data-search = '"+SECOND_STORE_TO_SELECT+"']/td/label/span")
WebElement secondSelectedStoreCheckBox;
```

Is there any way, I can parametrised that WebElement using pageFactory.
Not PageObject.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not support evaluation in annotation values. However there is a sort of workaround exists in Selenium.

You can change parts of values where the value is being processed. In Selenium the values are processed in those particular classes which extend `AbstractFindByBuilder` for given annotation.

So you can introduce your own annotation like `@ParameterizedFindBy` and integrate it into `PageFactory` harness like shown [here](https://www.webelement.click/en/parameterized_findby_annotation_in_selenium_page_object_java).

Here you can find [sources implementing such approach](https://github.com/webelement-click/parameterized-findby) and a short and descriptive example.